# Triangulated Irregular Networks from qhull

Tags: geometry, gis, computational-geometry, tesselation, lidar-data

I wanted to create TINs from 3D points (about 7 million in every file) using qhull.

can anyone suggest a place where i could probably see how to do this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used QHull since it is hard to integrate as a library into an existing project. Try out [Triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html); it is specialized for 2D and is very easy to use (it comes with an example of how to call it from other C code).

Answer (score 0):

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_irregular_network) says,

> A TIN comprises a triangular network
>   of vertices, known as mass points,
>   with associated coordinates in three
>   dimensions connected by edges to form
>   a triangular tessellation.
>   Three-dimensional visualizations are
>   readily created by rendering of the
>   triangular facets. In regions where
>   there is little variation in surface
>   height, the points may be widely
>   spaced whereas in areas of more
>   intense variation in height the point
>   density is increased.
>
> A TIN is typically based on a Delaunay
>   triangulation but its utility will be
>   limited by the selection of input data
>   points: well-chosen points will be
>   located so as to capture significant
>   changes in surface form, such as
>   topographical summits, breaks of
>   slope, ridges, valley floors, pits and
>   cols.

MATLAB can generate [3-D Delaunay tesselation](https://web.archive.org/web/20091205214125/http://www.mathworks.com:80/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/delaunay3.html) and [n-D Delaunay tesselation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunayn.html;jsessionid=14635405090aed4bb845db1220a0) using Qhull.

> *3-dimensional Delaunay tessellation - tetramesh is used to plot the tetrahedrons that form the corresponding simplex*

[image: 3D tesselation]
<sub>(source: [mathworks.com](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/delaunn.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend you a software package called [Streaming Computation of Delaunay Triangulations](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/sd/). On a normal computer it can compute

> Delaunay triangulations for large,
>   well-distributed data sets in 2D and
>   3D which can be greatly accelerated by
>   exploiting the natural spatial
>   coherence in a stream of points.

In terms of performance:

> We compute a billion-triangle terrain
>   representation for the Neuse River
>   system from 11.2 GB of LIDAR data in
>   48 minutes using only 70 MB of memory
>   on a laptop.

Here is teaser image on how it works:

[image: streaming delaunay]

You can check out this [video](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/sd/download/sd_video.avi) explaining their method/software.

Comment: This requires you to add markers in the input stream, something that the OP may not be able to do. For only 7 million vertices, an ordinary Delaunay triangulation algorithm could probably handle it with ordinary spatial hashing techniques.